# Does it take more energy to transmit electricity uphill?

Tags: gravity, electricity, electrons, mass

And if so, how much energy would have to be expended before you could possibly measure the loss (since gravity is very weak)? Let's say the load is 1000m above sea level, and the power source is at sea level?

Comment: When you say "Does it take more energy to transmit electricity uphill?", more energy relative to what? And when you say "electricity" do you mean current, and if so, do you mean moving negative charge or positive charge?

Answer (score 1):

It does not, for two reasons.

First, for every electron that you push uphill through the wire, another electron flows back downhill in the return wire and any work expended in lifting the one electron is returned by the electron that is coasting downhill.

Second, even if this were not true, the gravitational force is fundamentally smaller than the electromagnetic force by a factor greater than 30 orders of magnitude. This would make any such effect far, far too small to detect.

Comment: "Electricity" is a somewhat imprecise concept, but I would argue that it is carried by photons as well as charge carriers.  Photons do lose a tiny amount of energy as they travel uphill.

I completely agree that the size of the energy loss is undetectably small, though.

Comment: @Thorondor  Would not the formula 1/R^2 apply to any photon traveling (not just upwards, but in any direction?)  It is the amplitude of the wave that decreases, also termed "intensity".

Comment: @Thorondor, there is no photon transmission in metal wires carrying electric current.

Comment: @nielsnielsen In an electrical circuit, energy is transmitted through electromagnetic fields, i.e. by photons.  You can see this by calculating the Poynting vector inside the circuit.

Comment: @foolishmuse I'm not sure I understand what you're asking.  What is the relevance of the formula 1/R^2?

Answer (score 1):

I interpret the question as "Is a charged battery battery heavier than a discharge one?". A modern battery easily holds [0.4 MJ/kg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_density#Tables_of_energy_content), corresponding to a mass of 0.44 10$^{-11}$ kg/kg by the famous relation $E=mc^2$. So a fully charged battery weighs 4.4 trillionth more than an empty one.

Answer (score 1):

One kilogram contains 9*10^16 Joules.

Lifting a kilogram, or 9*10^16 Joules, 1000 meters takes 10 kJ.

So it looks like 1/9000000000000 of energy is lost when transmitting it from sea level to 1000m above sea level.

Here "lost" means "converted to potential energy".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using alternating current there is no loss since there is no net flow up.

If it is a direct current gravitation acts as if there was a voltage resisting the flow up (and enhancing it down) corresponding to $m_e g/q\approx 5.6\cdot 10^{-11}$ V/m. This is exceedingly small.

In a general relativity framework there would be a gravitational time dilation effect slowing the frequency, but AC power delivered seems to be independent of frequency.